# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Tengo un problema al implementar la libreria [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html) de angularJs con Laravel, la verdad no e dado con dicho error aca mi Services de angular

```
function PostServices($http, $q, CONFIG) {
  return {
        getPots: getPots,
      //  postCheck: postCheck,
        postSave: postSave
    };

    this.recipes = [];
    this.loading = false;
    this.page = 1;


   function getPots() {

     var url = CONFIG.APIURL + 'post/ajaxviewpublish?page=' + this.page;
     if (this.loading) return;
     this.loading = true;
     $http.get(url)
     .success(function (data) {
       console.log(data.message.data);
       for (var i = 0; i < data.message.data.length; i++) {
           this.recipes.push(data.message.data[i]);
       }
       this.page++;
       this.loading = false;
       recipes.loading = true; // This should prevent more code from being loaded.
   }.bind(this));


   }
   return getPots;
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined ese es el error que me aparece @Shaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez 'this' este haciendo referencia al objeto incorrecto, intenta lo siguiente:

```
...

var self=this;
self.recipes=[];
...

$http.get(url)
 .success(function (data) {
   console.log(data.message.data);
   for (var i = 0; i < data.message.data.length; i++) {
       self.recipes.push(data.message.data[i]);
   }
```

Talvez tengas que hacer lo mismo para `page` y `loading`

Comment: Es cierto, cuando el callback se ejecuta, `this` es un objeto totalmente diferente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.